# How to "intercept" a request that is made with cy.request with cypress

Tags: request, cypress, response, stub, intercept

As far as I understand cy.intercept() can be used to stub requests that the application itself makes.

Now I have a HTTP POST request with cy.request() in one of my custom commands in Cypress. Because this is a request made by cy.request() function I can't use cy.intercept() to stub the response of this request.

Is there any workaround to stub a respons of a request made with cy.request() ?

Now I have the following which is logging the real response correctly, but I want to keep this response even the when the remote server is offline:

```
  cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://sample.com/token',
        body: {
            username: "UserNameSample",
            password: "PasswordSample"
        },
        form: true,
    }).then(response => {
        cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body))
    })
```

Which is resulting in the following printscreen of the comment log in cypress.:
[image]

Comment: Are you just logging the response? Are you storing that value anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can try for `fetch` interface to make the network calls instead:

```
cy.intercept({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://sample.com/token',
  },
  {
    // your stubbed response

  }).as('createToken').then(() => {
      fetch('https://sample.com/token', {method: 'POST'})
        .then((response) => {
          cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body))
        })
    })
  cy.wait('@createToken').its('response.body')
```

*P.S. I've not tested it, so it might need some adjustments*